# Storing Results of my query in session in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Suppose I have a Registration table with `id`, `name`, `emailid`, `passowrd`, etc. attributes.

Now, in my login form, I have 2 options to put `emailid` and `password` to login.

My question is how do I show the name (not the email_id) of the logged in user in the next page's label?  I already know how to retrieve the email as a string from the textbox as well as how to show it in next page's label.

But, in this case, I think I have to run a query to get the name of the user from the database with the help of the email_id that can be retrieved from the textbox of the login form.

I don't know how to put any results obtained from query in session.

Comment: what about separating your question in paragraphs..?

Comment: i am learning asp.net with C#... so any help would be appreciated .:)

Comment: I mean that your question could be way more readable if you separate the text in paragraphs :D

Comment: { 
string q_login = "select * from Table_registration where email='" + TextBox_logemail.Text + "' and password='" + TextBox_logpass.Text + "'";

        SqlDataAdapter da_login = new SqlDataAdapter(q_login, con);

        DataTable dt_login = new DataTable();

        da_login.Fill(dt_login);

        if (dt_login.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string usename = "select name from Table_registration where email='" + TextBox_logemail.Text + "'";

            Session["name"] = usename;

            Response.Redirect("Inbox.aspx");
        }
i tried this but did not work.

Comment: Voting to close. The problem has nothing to do with putting the query results into session. The OP doesn't even seem to know how to execute the query!

Comment: Please tell me you're not storing the password in plain-text?

Comment: Also: the code in that comment is vulnerable to sql injection. It's practically begging to get badly hacked.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I fixed it after getting help from Hanlet Escano who Posted 1 solution before.:).The solution will be like that-
{ string q_login = "select * from Table_registration where email='" + TextBox_logemail.Text + "' and password='" + TextBox_logpass.Text + "'"; SqlDataAdapter da_login = new SqlDataAdapter(q_login, con); DataTable dt_login = new DataTable(); da_login.Fill(dt_login); if (dt_login.Rows.Count > 0) { String username = Convert.ToString ( dt_login.Rows[0]["name"]); Session["name"] = username; Response.Redirect("Inbox.aspx");

Comment: You're still storing the password in plain text and you're still vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You'll be lucky if you go a month before giving away your users passwords to a hacker.

Answer (score 0):

```
Session["Name"] = nameFromQuery;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will only need the username store it in the session. The way I usually have it set up, I have a `Users` class, and I put the entire object in the session, because I usually will need something other than the UserName. Everytime I need to check something I cast my object session back to my user class:

```
public class Users
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

then put it in session like so:

```
Session["LoggedUser"] = myUser;
```

to retrieve it from the session:

```
if (Session["LoggedUser"] != null)
{
    Users usr = (Users)Session["LoggedUser"];
    myLabel.Text = usr.Name
}
```

Comment: { string q_login = "select * from Table_registration where email='" + TextBox_logemail.Text + "' and password='" + TextBox_logpass.Text + "'"; SqlDataAdapter da_login = new SqlDataAdapter(q_login, con); DataTable dt_login = new DataTable(); da_login.Fill(dt_login); if (dt_login.Rows.Count > 0) { string usename = "select name from Table_registration where email='" + TextBox_logemail.Text + "'"; Session["name"] = usename; Response.Redirect("Inbox.aspx"); } i tried this but did not work properly.can you help according to my code.

Comment: @SantanuMaulik you are only putting the username in the session. What do you need help with? Be careful with sql injection and the way you access you database.

Comment: Escano in the label of inbox.aspx it is showing the full sql query instead of the result from sql query :(

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that is what you are doing. After you check dt_login.Rows.Count > 0 your username string should be something like `dt_login.Rows[0]["UserNameField"]`. Right now you are assigning your select to the TextBox, it will not work that way.

Comment: Oh! yes.. finally that worked what you suggested. String username = Convert.ToString ( dt_login.Rows[0]["name"]); this worked ..ty:)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this

## Storing in session

```
HttpSessionState curSession = HttpContext.Current.Session;
curSession["SessionVariableName"] = result;
```

## Retrieving from session

```
HttpSessionState curSession = HttpContext.Current.Session;
result = curSession["SessionVariableName"];
```

You would have to cast the object to the correct type when retrieving it though.

Say that the result variable is declared like so.

```
String result;
```

Then you would write

```
result = (String)curSession["SessionVariableName"];
```

or

```
result = curSession["SessionVariableName"].ToString();
```

Let me know if this helps you at all.

Comment: Not so clear to me .. m new in asp.net . so plz consider my code posted in the comment section & tell me what is wrong there in my code? any suggestion?